# how to reduce the dimension of the document embedding?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding

Let us assume that I have a set of document embeddings. (D) 
Each of document embedding is consisting of N number of word vectors where each of these pre-trained vector has 300 dimensions.

The corpus would be represented as [D,N,300].

My question is that, what would be the best way to reduce [D,N,300] to [D,1, 300]. How should I represent the document in a single vector instead of N vectors?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked on datascience.SE.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that what you are looking for is [doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html). Using this you can convert the whole document into a one, 300-dimensional vector. You can use it like this:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(your_documents)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=300, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)
```

This will train the model on your data and you will be able to represent each document with only one vector as you specified in the question.

You can run inferrance with:

```
vector = model.infer_vector(doc_words)
```

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Instead of retraining the corpus from the beginning, I would like to use existing pre-trained word vectors. Is it possible to provide my doc corpus as a set of pre-trained word vectors into this model and get the results from there?

Comment: I’m not sure that I understand what you want to do. When you say word vectors do you mean document vectors? Basically, you can do whatever you want but just have to keep an eye on the dimensions. You can definitely try this what you suggested but I think you will get the best results if you train it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common and fairly (perhaps surprisingly) effective to simply average the word vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been using this technique so far but I want to make sure that other advanced techniques are not producing far better result than the current simple approach

Comment: For next steps, I would also recommend looking into SIF (smooth inverse frequency) pooling for combining word embeddings into sentence embeddings and P-SIF (partitioned  inverse frequency) pooling for document embeddings.

Answer (score 1):

Good question but all the answers will result in the some loss of information. The best way for you is to use a Bi-LSTM/GRU layer and provide your word embeddings as input to that layer. And take the output of last time step.

The output of last timestep will have all the contextual information of document both in forward and backward direction. And hence, this is the best way to get what you want as the model learns the representation.

Note that, the larger the document, the more loss of information.